# Why is transconductance vs gate voltage graph for a mosfet not constant when drain current is a linear function of gate voltage?(in linear region)

Tags: mosfet, transconductance

Id=Kn(Vg-Vth)Vd in the linear region
This should imply that the transconductance is constant for constant Vd(drain voltage) but the graph is something else

Comment: Show the graph you are talking about.

Comment: **Why** should \$gm\$ (the transconductance) remain constant? \$gm\$ is defined **at a certain biasing point** (\$V_{gs}, V_{ds}, I_d\$ have a certain DC value). If you change the biasing point, you get a different \$gm\$. You change the gate voltage => you get a different \$gm\$.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yours is the obvious answer, I think.